# 2D discrete colour plot using discrete variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, simulation, contour

I am looking for a way to graph some data in a human readable format. I have data from simulations that contains a frame number, protein residue number and protein secondary structure state. Frame number as integers and the secondary structure state as strings. For example:

0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

1   'H'   'H'   'H'   '0'   'H'   '0'   'H'   'H'   'H'   'b'   'H'   'H'   'S'
2   'H'   'H'   'H'   'H'   'H'   'S'   'H'   '0'   'b'   'H'   'H'   'H'   'H'

Column 0 contains the frame number and the rest of the columns correspond to the state of the residue numbers (i.e the state of residue number 6 at frame 1 is '0' and at frame 2 is 'S').

I would like to produce a 2D plot of frame number against residue number that plots a specific colour depending on the string given in the 'Struc' column. Manual control of the colours given to strings is preferable (to avoid similar colours).

Can anyone direct me to any specific modules/submodules that will allow me to do this?

Note: This is for a large set of data, files could reach 2000 frames for over 1000 residues so computational efficiency is required. I'm also not averse to reformatting the data, should it make the plotting easier/possible/faster.

Comment: If I understand your explanation you want some thing like heatmap? Look at the example https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following example:

1. You define the data first (or you'll read these in from a file).
2. define a color mapping for the single values (see `colormap`, below and the [color documentation of matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/colors_api.html))
3. a function will map these letters/values to a number, consider it an index. the same index will be used for the color accessing
4. draw the image with nearest neighbor interpolation and the provided colors

My suggestion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

def toImage(frames, colormap):
    keys = list(colormap.keys())
    colors = [colormap[key] for key in keys]

    image = [[keys.index(val) for val in row[1:]] for row in frames]
    return image, colors

frames = [[0, 'H', 'H', 'H', '0', 'H', '0', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'b', 'H', 'H', 'S'],
          [1, 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'S', 'H', '0', 'b', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H']]

colormap = {'H': 'red',
            '0': 'green', 
            'S': '#4eefff',
            'b': 'b'}

image, colors = toImage(frames, colormap)

plt.imshow(image, cmap = ListedColormap(colors), interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.show()
```

surely, there's a lot to tweak (e.g. I left out frame numbers completely, adapt the `y`-ticks appriopriately, ...) but it should get you started

Comment: This worked perfectly, only thing to add is for data sets that aren't NxN arrrays, it's best to add in the 'aspect' argument to the imshow function to make the colour map have the dimensions that you'd personally like ( my test data set for this was approx 900x100 so the colour map looked very off to begin with ). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate method using a [Seaborn heatmap](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) that may be better suited for large datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns

# create dataset
residue_state_options = ['H', '0', 'S', 'b']
residue_state_arr = np.random.choice(residue_state_options,
                                     (100, 100), p=[0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

df = pd.DataFrame(residue_state_arr)

# map dataset to numbers
residue_state_map = {'H': 0, '0': 1, 'S': 2, 'b': 3}
df.replace(residue_state_map, inplace=True)

ax = sns.heatmap(df)
```

For a slightly more sophisticated plot, plus control of colors you could take out the last line and instead do something like

```
colors = ['#edf8fb', '#b2e2e2', '#66c2a4', '#238b45']

grid_kws = {'height_ratios': (0.9, 0.05), 'hspace': 0.2}
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(2, gridspec_kw=grid_kws)
ax = sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, cmap=ListedColormap(colors),
                 xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
                 cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'})

cbar_ax.set_xticklabels(residue_state_options)
cbar_ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0.125,  0.375,  0.625,  0.875])
```

To achieve this plot.

[image]